# 2 question about Probability

Tags: probability, random-variables

1. How to prove：If $\tilde{X} = X$ a.s., then $\mathbb{E}(\tilde{X} |\mathcal{G}) = E(X | \mathcal{G})$ a.s.
2. Let X and Y be real integrable random variables. Show that $\mathbb{E}(X |\mathcal{G}) \leq E(Y | \mathcal{G})$ a.s. $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathbb{E}(X |1_{A}) \leq E(Y | 1_{A})$, $\forall A\in G$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: They both are corollaries of the definition of conditional expectation. Obviously, you haven't tried anything.

Comment: I amswered your first question, but you should put down what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. If you do that, I'll help you with the second question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose $X, \tilde{X}$ are random variables measurable w.r.t probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, and $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ is a sub-sigma algebra. Recall the conditional expectation of $X$ wrt $\mathcal{G}$ is defined as a random variable satisfying the following properties

1. $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable.
2. $\int_A \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}] d\mathbb{P} = \int_A X d\mathbb{P}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{G}$.
   and similarly for $\tilde{X}$.

Recall that by the Radon-Nikodym theorem, the conditional expectation always exists and is unique a.s.. Now given your assumption on $X,\tilde{X}$, we have for all $A \in \mathcal{G}$
$$\int_A \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}] d\mathbb{P} = \int_A X d\mathbb{P} = \int_A \tilde{X} d\mathbb{P} = \int_A \mathbb{E}[\tilde{X}|\mathcal{G}] d\mathbb{P}.$$

There is a theorem that says if two random variables have integrals that agree on all events, then they are the same a.s., giving you your result.

The answer to your second question has a similar approach. Try it out and let me know if you want me to clarify any of the details.

Comment: Thank you very much， I will try the second one.

Comment: I have tried second one, use the same conditions in Q1, and  we suppose that $\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y | \mathcal{G}]$ a.s., we can have $\forall A\in \mathcal{G}$, $\int_{A} \mathbb{E}[X| \mathcal{G}] d\mathbb{P}= \int_{A} X d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{E}[X1_{A}] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y1_{A}]=\int_{A} Yd\mathbb{P} = \int_{A} \mathbb{E}[Y | \mathcal{G}] d\mathbb{P} $. But I don't know how to prove the inverse.

Comment: For the inverse, we need to use $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}] 1_{A}] \leq \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[Y | \mathcal{G}] 1_{A}]$?

Comment: @Lin Valentino tldr: Yes. For the reverse direction you need to use a theorem which says for two random variables $X,Y$ over probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, \mathbb{P})$, $X \leq Y$ a.s. if and only if $\int_A X \leq \int_A Y$ for all $A \in \mathcal{G}$. The proof of this is not very hard (it's really a measure-theoretic statement rather than a probability-specific one). If you get stuck, it should be in one of the earlier chapters in your textbook that covers expectation. You can also bootstrap this result to get the corresponding theorem for $X=Y$ a.s. mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I have tried, but I’m not sure my answer is correct

Comment: Assume that $\mathbb{E}[X | 1_{A}] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y | 1_{A}] , \forall A \in \mathcal{G}$, Note A = {$\mathbb{E}[X | \mathcal{G}] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y | \mathcal{G}]$}, then $\mathbb{E}[X 1_{A}] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y 1_{A}] $, $that means \mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{E}[1_{A}] \geq 0 since 1_{A} is non negative r.a.$, so we have $\int \mathbb{E}[X1_{A}]d\mathbb{P} \leq \int \mathbb{E}[Y1_{A}]d\mathbb{P} $, then by the tower property, $ \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X| A]| \mathcal{G}] \leq  \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y| A]| \mathcal{G}] $, $ \mathbb{E}[X| \mathcal{G}] \leq  \mathbb{E}[ Y| \mathcal{G}] $ a.s.

Comment: @LinValentino It's a bit hard to fully understand your answer because of some formatting issues. I'll expand on what I meant in my earlier comment: Both $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}],\mathbb{E}[Y|\mathcal{G}]$ are $\mathcal{G}$-measureable random variables. Using the definition of conditional expectation, for all $A \in \mathcal{G}$, $\int_A \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}] = \int_A X \leq \int_A Y = \int_A \mathbb{E}[Y|\mathcal{G}]$. Since $A$ is arbitrary, we can use the theorem I mentioned. I highly recommend familiarizing yourself with that theorem and its proof, it is extremely important.

Comment: Okay, Thank you a lot for your answer, it’s very helpful.